# Powershell Get Files from Directory and search for them in another Directory

Tags: powershell

Dear wise Stackoverflow Community

Is it possible with powershell, to get all filenames in a directory and search for them each in another directory?

Something like:

Path A (C:\Temp):

```
C:\Temp\Test2\Test.docx
C:\Temp\Test\test.txt
C:\Temp\Test\file.html`
```

and search for each file (Test.docx,test.txt,file.html)  in a different path e.g. C:\Filesnew ?

and in the best case, the export to csv would be something like:

```
| Filename  | Filepath                 | Found? | FoundIn                                 |
| --------  | ------------------------ |--------| ----------------------------------------|
| Test.docx | C:\Temp\Test2\Test.docx  | y      | C:\Filesnew\TransferedFiles\Test.docx   |
| test.txt  | C:\Temp\Test\test.txt    | n      |                                         |
| file.html | C:\Temp\Test\file.html   | y      | C:\Filesnew\webfiles\file.html          |
```

I'm currently stuck at this code:

```
$files = gci -r *   | select-object name, fullname
foreach ($file in $files)
{
  gci -path C:\Filesnew -recurse | where {$_.Name -match $file.Name} | select-object $files.Name $files.fullname, $file.fullname | Export-CSV C:\test.csv  
}
```

Can you help me out?

Comment: Using this [`Join-Object script`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join)/[`Join-Object Module`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule) (see also: [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026)): `gci -path C:\Filesnew -recurse| select-object name, fullname |LeftJoin $files -on name -name FoundIn`

Comment: You need to search for just the filename without the paths.  So you need to remove the name of the file from the path before searching for the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires a bit of logic, ideally the more efficient way to go about this is to have a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2) with all File Names and their corresponding Absolute Paths excluding the target directory (`C:\Filesnew`) for fast lookups.

```
$targetDir = 'C:\Filesnew'

$queue = [Collections.Generic.Queue[IO.DirectoryInfo]]::new()
$queue.Enqueue((Get-Item C:\))

# This logic below builds a map having:
#  - Keys as the FileName
#  - Values as the corresponding Absolute Paths for each FileName
$map = @{}
while($queue.Count) {
    try {
        $target = $queue.Dequeue()
        foreach($item in $target.EnumerateFileSystemInfos()) {
            if($item.FullName.StartsWith($targetDir, $true, $null)) {
                # exclude the `$targetDir` and any directory or file in it
                continue
            }

            if($item -is [IO.DirectoryInfo]) {
                $queue.Enqueue($item)
                continue
            }

            if(-not $map.ContainsKey($item.Name)) {
                $map[$item.Name] = [Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
            }

            $map[$item.Name].Add($item.FullName)
        }
    }
    catch {
        # you can add error handling here but most errors will be Access Denied
        # can also leave blank here to ignore errors
    }
}

# now that we have our map of FileNames and Absolute Paths
# query the target Directory
Get-ChildItem $targetDir -Recurse -File | ForEach-Object {
    # construct the desired output
    [pscustomobject]@{
        FileName = $_.Name
        FilePath = $_.Fullname
        Found    = ('n', 'y')[$map.ContainsKey($_.Name)]
        FoundIn  = $map[$_.Name] -join ', '
    }
# Export the output to CSV
} | Export-Csv C:\test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```